# @Version causing TransientPropertyValueException a on save

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I am currently working on a Spring boot project and I am trying to add versioning with @Version to my entities but it's causing this error when I try saving two related entities :

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : com.app.product.Product.productIssuer -> com.app.productissuer.ProductIssuer
```

My test class

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@Transactional
public class ProductControllerIT {

    @Test
    public void create() throws Exception {
    
        Product product = new Product();
    
        ProductIssuer productIssuer = [...]
    
        em.persist(productIssuer);
        em.flush();
    
        // Here on debugger productIssuer got an id
    
        product.setProductIssuer(productIssuer);
    
        restProductMockMvc.perform(post("/v2/rest/product")
                .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(product)))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated());
    }
```

The entity that I am trying to save :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private UUID id;

    @Version
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long entityVersion;

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn
    ProductIssuer productIssuer;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "product_issuer")
public class ProductIssuer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private UUID id;

    @Version
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long entityVersion;
}
```

The controller and the service use to save :

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/v2/rest/product")
public class ProductController {

    @PostMapping()
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ProductDTO create(@RequestBody final ProductDTO productDTO) {
        Product product = modelMapper.map(productDTO, Product.class);

        productService.save(product);
        return modelMapper.map(product, ProductDTO.class);
    }
}

@Slf4j
@Transactional
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProductService {

    public Product save(Product product) {
        return productRepository.save(product);
    }
}
```

For information I went through debug mode on my controller, service and repository and the productIssuer do have an id through all of those classes.

UPDATE : The entityVersion of my productIssuer is null when I arrived in the save of the repository (because of the mapping DTO->Entity) and it seems to cause this error. But am I supposed to get the entity from the database before saving every time in order to get the version ?

Comment: can you  provide your controller action for `/v2/rest/product` and related service code

Comment: I have added them, sorry for the delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you need to change your `ProductService.save` method. you first need to query the `productIssuer` instance from db. then set it to `product` and then save the `product` instance. can you please try this. here is the pseudocode:

```
public Product save(Product product) {
    ProductIssuer productIssuer = productIssuerRepository.findById(product.getProductIssuer().getId()).get();
    product.setProductIssuer(productIssuer);
    return productRepository.save(product);
}
```